# Springboot mockito mock a field

Tags: mockito

I want to mock the TreeMap in Service class, I tried to mock using `TreeMap<String, String> requestsMap = Mockito.mock(TreeMap.class);` But the map is getting null at runtime.

```
 @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @SpringBootTest
    @WebAppConfiguration
    public class ServiceTest {
    
        @InjectMocks
        private Service service;
    
        @Before
        public void init() {
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        }
    
        @Test
        public void test() {
            TreeMap<String, String> requestsMap = Mockito.mock(TreeMap.class);
        }
    }
    
    @Service
    public class Service {
    
     private TreeMap<String, String> requestsMap = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Service class doesn't actually do anything but declare and initialize the requestMap to null. Also, your test method doesn't do anything other than declare a mock requestMap.

In addition to the code you have, write a method in the Service that uses the request map and just declare/autowire the requestMap. In your test, use the @Mock annotation on a declaration of your mock requestMap. Finally, use the mocked requestMap in your test.

For example:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ServiceTest {

    @Mock
    TreeMap<String, String> requestsMap;

    @InjectMocks
    private Service service;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
      when(requestMap.get("foo")).thenReturn("bar");
      String result = service.doSomething();
      assertEquals(result, "bar");
        
    }
}

@Service
public class Service {

  @Autowired
  private TreeMap<String, String> requestsMap;

  public String doSomething() {
     return requestMap.get("foo");
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to initialize the map in test?

Comment: Well, if the map is a mock, you don't have to initialize it. If it's a regular map, you can initialize it as a new map in the @Before method, and then put the values into it in each test method (assuming you want to test different map values).